# Nuget restore from github package manager giving 403

Tags: github, nuget, nuget-server

We have a private set of nuget packages in GitHub. Until recently, I was able to restore packages from this repository and view them in the package manager. Now, I'm getting 403 errors:

Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MyCompany/download/MyPackage/index.json'.
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).

This source is setup in my Nuget.Config and previously worked.

What I've tried:

- Regenerated my PAT
- Deleted my PAT and created a new one.
- Cleared the Nuget Cache
- Cleared temp files from %AppData%\local\temp
- Removed the VSCredentials_nuget.pkg.github.com credential. Also tried editing the credential and pasting in my new PAT.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: try using fiddler, and configure it to decrypt https traffic, and check if NuGet is using the new or the old PAT on the HTTP requests it sends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I forgot the "Configure SSO" step to authorize the PAT for SSO. Once I did that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to piggy back off this for anyone else who ended up here like me.

My issue was I was passing in my PAT via an organization level secret. I am on the "Team" level plan and apparently you can't use org level secrets in Action unless you have "Enterprise". I moved my PAT to a repository level secret and then everything worked.